# Application is forced close when connecting to SSH with JSch in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, ssh, jsch

I'm really confusing to connect SSH with JSch in Android studio. I want to create an app that can remote SSH like connectBot but it has a GUI not only terminal. Here's my code

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import com.jcraft.jzlib.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    executeRemoteCommand("username","password","hostname", 22);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    }

    public static String executeRemoteCommand(
            String username,
            String password,
            String hostname,
            //String command,
            int port) throws Exception {

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
        session.setPassword(password);

        // Avoid asking for key confirmation
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(prop);

        session.connect();

        // SSH Channel
        ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec)
                session.openChannel("exec");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        channelssh.setOutputStream(baos);

        // Execute command
        channelssh.setCommand("mkdir /home/beny/test");
        channelssh.connect();
        channelssh.disconnect();

        return baos.toString();
    }
}
```

When I'm compiled app has forced close. Whats wrong with my code? Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may be, that you try to do a network operation on the GUI thread.

That's not allowed on Android.

You have to start a background thread for all network operations:

- [How do I fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6343166/850848)
- [Using another thread for "networking" , in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16213020/850848)